# How to get the value from the database that the user selected?

Tags: laravel

I have household_heads table that has the id column for each household_head.

I also have s_d_o_h_s table that contains the column for Social Determinants of Health such as the Residence, House Construction etc.

The s_d_o_h_categories table have sdoh_id and category column that indicates the categories for each sdoh.

The s_d_o_h_category_households table have sdoh_category_id an household_head_id that indicates the sdoh_category_id the household_head chooses.

**controller to get the sdoh categories from the sdoh:
**

```
    $residenceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Residence')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $constructionCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'House Construction')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $waterSourceCategories = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'Water Source')->first()->sdoh_category;

//etc...
```

**views**

```
@foreach($residenceCategories as $residenceCategory)
    @if($residenceCategory->sdoh_category_id === $household->household_head_id)
     {{ $residenceCategory->category}}
    @endif
@endforeach

//etc...
```

but the error is this :

[image]

I want to display in the views the categories the household_head chooses.

this is my s_d_o_h_category_households:

[image]

if household_head number 25 chooses the sdoh_category_id number 1, I want it to display the category in the views.